# pass value from one onclick func to another onclick func

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to pass one variable from one click to another click function.

Not sure if it is possible. I did some research previously but could not find a suitable solution.

```
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    var whichid = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(whichid);
});

$('#button').click(function () {
    //get the clicked id value from previous click function
});
```

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/g7xNv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.data()` to store which element was clicked

```
$('.clickme').click (function() {
    var whichid = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#button').data('whichid', whichid);
    alert(whichid);
});

$('#button').click (function() {
    alert( $('#button').data('whichid'));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g7xNv/2/)

Comment: Excellent Satpal...nice one...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You're propably in the scope of the surrounding `$().ready()` call anyways, so you can do this without a problem:

```
var whichid = 0;

$('.clickme').click(function () {
    whichid = $(this).attr("id");
});

$('#button').click(function () {
    alert(whichid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way is using global variables:

```
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    var whichid = $(this).attr("id");
    window["whichid"] = whichid;
    alert(whichid);
});

$('#button').click(function () {
    alert(window["whichid"] || "not clicked yet");
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7xNv/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to use Satpal's solution as I have lots of this kind of onclick events.

Comment: Sure, actually using `.data()` is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a global variable, and set value to this variable.
for example you can do this:

```
var globalVar = null;

$('.clickme').click(function () {
    var whichid = $(this).attr("id");
    globalVar = whichid
    console.log(whichid); // console.log() is more better than alert to debug
});



$('#button').click(function () {
        //get the clicked id value from previous click function
        console.log(globalVar);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add a **hidden input field** to store the value of recently clicked id :

as

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_clicked_id" id="last_clicked_id">
```

Now save the last clicked id into the hidden element

JS:

```
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    var whichid = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(whichid);
    $('#last_clicked_id').val(whichid);
});


$('#button').click(function () {
    //get the clicked id value from previous click function
    var last_clicked = $('#last_clicked_id').val();
    alert('last_clicked = '+last_clicked);
});
```